# How can I add a Singleton class to a reference assembly for NuGet

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to create a NuGet package for Windows UWP which is built for different architectures - x86, x64 and ARM. As per the NuGet bug I opened - [nuget restore always restores for ARM not x86,x64](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1788) , I will need to add a "surface area implementation" of my classes to the `ref` folder of NuGet.

One of my public classes is a singleton, meaning it has a static method. How can I add a static method to the "surface area implementation" for the `ref` folder ? I'm assuming the `ref` folder needs to contain an interface defining the public classes and methods of the implementation in my DLL.

From https://docs.nuget.org/create/uwp-create

> ref is a new, optional, directory that contains .NET assemblies
>   defining the public surface (public types and methods) for an
>   application to compile against. The assemblies in this folder may have
>   no implementation, they are purely used to define surface area for the
>   compiler. If the package has no ref directory, then the lib is both
>   the reference assembly and the implementation assembly.

Answer (score 1):

If your API needs a static method then just add the static method into your reference assembly.

A reference assembly may have no implementation, so it just defines types, or it may contain implementation logic.

If you need platform specific logic and still want a static implementation in your reference assembly then this is possible. An example of this is the [PCLStorage NuGet package](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage). This has a static FileSystem class which has a static property called Current.

```
public static class FileSystem
{
    static Lazy<IFileSystem> _fileSystem = new Lazy<IFileSystem>(() => CreateFileSystem(), System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);

    public static IFileSystem Current
    {
        get
        {
            IFileSystem ret = _fileSystem.Value;
            if (ret == null)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }

    static IFileSystem CreateFileSystem()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So your reference assembly can define a static class and static property, or even a static method, which has no implementation. The PCLStorage's FileSystem class has a private static CreateFileSystem method in its reference assembly:

Then in your platform specific assembly your CreateFileSystem creates its own class which implements the IFileSystem interface. In your case the static method could be public instead of private.

The PCLStorage project uses conditionally defined code to create the different platform specific and reference assemblies:

```
    static IFileSystem CreateFileSystem()
    {
#if NETFX_CORE || WINDOWS_PHONE
        return new WinRTFileSystem();
#elif SILVERLIGHT
        return new IsoStoreFileSystem();
#elif FILE_SYSTEM
        return new DesktopFileSystem();
#else
        return null;
#endif
    }
```

This all works if all the names and versions of your assemblies are the same for all platforms, including the reference assemblies. This is the [bait and switch trick](http://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/) that Paul Betts discusses in his post on the [Bait and Switch PCL trick](http://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/). In Paul Betts example a Portable Class Library (PCL) is being used as a reference assembly and he shows another very similar approach to having a static method in the reference assembly class and a platform specific implementation in another assembly.

Comment: Well, that's the conundrum. Since my reference assembly cannot have any implementation, it must be an interface or abstract class and I cannot add a static method to an interface or abstract class

Comment: Your reference assembly can have implementation if you want it to.

Comment: I'm constrained to not have the implementation in the reference library because my libraries are not AnyCPU - they are different for x86, ARM and x64 .

Comment: Then you can either do what you suggested, which is to convert the code to use an interface or abstract class. Or you can keep a static method, but have it use an interface or abstract class so the platform specific implementation can be used when it is needed. For example, you could have a way to register the platform specific implementation with the static class.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the answer. Can you give me a little example when you say "you could have a way to register the platform specific implementation with the static class" .